# Android rss parse - what method to use?

Tags: android, rss, parsing

What would be the easiest way to parse an rss feed? Are there any already done easy(fast to implement) methods out there?
All the posts I could find on the topic were many years old. Any new technologies out there that are worthy of attention? Or should I just make my own parser?

Edit: please link to a usage method/tutorial too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bigger XML i would recomend a serial XML parser like `SAX` - it's build in: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/package-summary.html

For examples just search in Google - there are milions out there: http://www.google.at/search?q=sax+android+tutorial

Comment: Yeah but I can't find an easy one. My dream would be a rssparser.jar with a rssparser.seturi(), rssparser.readresponse() methods. :D

Comment: What about this one: http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

It is well structured and quite that, what you'r looking for.

Comment: We choose the saxparser method, thanks for the tip!
It was a lot easier to understand, than the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

For just reading it out, you can use DOM parser, which is very simple to use and to understand.
And: It is part of the android API

Comment: Checking it...
Any tutorials/examples about DOM?

Comment: try this out: Once it was my guide for dom. by the way it is about parsing RSS ;-)

http://www.brics.dk/~amoeller/XML/programming/domexample.html

Comment: Please comment your code, if you post it somewhere. At the first and second look, I have no idea what does what or where or why. :)

Comment: sry, this is not my own code ;-) The main issue is, to create a multipath tree and read out the nodes...this is basically what this code above does

Comment: "Once it was my guide..." Sorry, I misread :)
My issues is time, I don't want to waste time, on something that has already been done before. But it looks like, there is no real easy to use method out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the source code from [Android XML Parser Performance](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3824221_2/Android-XML-Parser-Performance.htm) as an example. I stick to `SAXParser` though `XmlPullParser` is good as well.
DOM is not the best option for a memory-constrained device (unless you want to manipulate the tree which you don't).

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2"></uses-sdk>
what a dinosaur :D
checking it...